# How to get current environment name?

Tags: github, github-actions

In GitHub Workflow I'm looking for a [build-in variable](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/variables#default-environment-variables) which would contain the name of the current [GH deployment environment](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/targeting-different-environments/using-environments-for-deployment) (e.g. `"staging"`) or be blank/unset if no such thing exist.

Since there doesn't seem to be a build-in variable for it (perhaps I'm overlooking it?), is there another way that this value can be obtained from *within* a pipeline step?

Here's an example workflow:

```yaml
jobs:

  job1:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: uat

    steps:
      - name: 'Print name'
        run: echo "GH deployment env : ..."

  job2:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: staging

    steps:
      - name: 'Print name'
        run: echo "GH deployment env : ..."
```

Comment: You can access **environment** name from **deployment** object. Ref [How environments relate to deployments](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/targeting-different-environments/using-environments-for-deployment#how-environments-relate-to-deployments)

Comment: @Haridarshan: How would that be available to the pipeline?  Can you make an example?

Comment: I haven't tried it but I think you can check it by printing the github/job context object like this `run: echo '${{ toJSON(github) }}'`

Comment: To be clear, the value needs (in my mind) to either be available as a [build-in variable](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/variables#default-environment-variables) or indirectly in one of the [contexts vars](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts). Otherwise I just cannot figure out how I would use it from within a Step.

Comment: Is there a `deployment` object in your job github context? If I remember correctly, in that case there would be 2 fields `environment` and`original_environment` there (_edit: I found an example in this [workflow run](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/actions/runs/4934758879/jobs/8820196236), in the Dump Github Context step_): Using `event.deployment.environment` should return the value in the workflow.

Comment: The `github` context (when printed using `${{ toJSON(github) }}`) does not have any `deployment` object, nor can I find any [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#github-context) that it is supposed to have that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried different ways, but the only one that actually worked was using the matrix configuration.

https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#matrix-context

```
name: GitHub Actions Demo
run-name: ${{ github.actor }} is testing out GitHub Actions 
on: 
  push:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  Deploy-DEV:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        environment: [DEV]    

    steps:            
      - run: echo " Deploying to ${{ matrix.environment }}."            

  Deploy-QA:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: Deploy-DEV
    strategy:
      matrix:
        environment: [QA]    

    steps:            
      - run: echo " Deploying to ${{ matrix.environment }}."
```

[image: Github workflow]

[image: Deploying to DEV]

Comment: Thanks. I haven't tried your suggestion, but you've documented it well. Kudos. I'll accept your answer.